# Add Element UI DatePicker to Vue FullCalendar CustomButton

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, element-ui

Using jQuery, we can easily do DOM manipulation to viewRender so we can add extra DOM/actions that we want to the existing HTML element.

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    customButtons: {
        newButton: {
           text: 'New Button', // if possible I want this to have an element ui datepicker component here
           click: function() {
              //I want to show date picker when this button is clicked
           }
        }
    }
})
```

However, I want to apply this in VueFullCalendar where an element UI date picker is shown, where we can only do as such:

```
<full-calendar :events="events" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating a custom toolbar. Fullcalendar has its API where we can use such as:

Declaration:

```
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('fCalendar');
    this.fCalendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
         //options
    })
    this.fCalendar.render();
```

Go to today method example:

```
this.fCalendar.today() // go to today
```

Note that I am using v4 alpha.

Answer (score 1):

The `vue-fullcalendar` pacakage is just a wrapper around the `jQuery` package, so passing a ref to it will give you the underlying DOM instance that the `fullcalendar` was attached to:

```
<full-calendar :events"events" ref="fullcalendar">
```

With the `ref` created, we can get the DOM element by doing:

```
this.$refs.fullcalendar.fullcalendar({
  //your jQuery logic here
})
```

But this isn't really what you want, is it? You want the `vue` way of using bindings and not manipulating the DOM.

Unfortunately you'll have to change packages for that as this isn't at true Vue component, but rather just a wrapper around the jQuery component